# Javascript - write duplicates in array to html

Tags: javascript, arrays, duplicates

I need to write a function that creates an array of random numbers between 1 and 20 and prints each number in a table. If it's a duplicate of a number that has already been generated, it needs to be highlighted in red.

My issue is that after the first duplicate has been printed in red, if there is another, it would not be printed in red. I can't get it to work for more than one time.

Here's the output:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
function randomNumberTable(){
    // create array with random numbers
    var nums = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        nums[i] = randomNumber();
    }

    // create header row
    document.writeln("<table border = \"1\">");
    document.writeln("<th>Index</th>");
    document.writeln("<th>Number</th>");

    // if duplicate, print in red, else, black
    for(var j = 0; j <= nums.length-1; j++){
        var isExist = numberExists(nums[j], nums, j);   
        if (isExist){
            document.writeln("<tr>");
            document.writeln("<td>" + j + "</td>");
            document.writeln("<td><font color=\"red\">" + nums[j] + "</font></td>");
            document.writeln("</tr>");
        }
        else{
            document.writeln("<tr>");
            document.writeln("<td>" + j + "</td>");
            document.writeln("<td>" + nums[j] + "</td>");
            document.writeln("</tr>");
        }
    }
}

// generate a random number between 1 and 20
function randomNumber(){
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*20) + 1;
    return randomNum;
}

// checking if the number exists 
function numberExists(num, myArray, myIndex){
    for(var k = 0; k < myIndex; k++){
        if(num == myArray[k])
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `numberExists` will always `return` on the first iteration...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your `numberExists` function like this.

```
function numberExists(num, myArray, myIndex){
    for(var k = 0; k < myIndex; k++){
        if(num == myArray[k])
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't catch that mistake! I thought it was in the randomNumberTable() for loop, haha. Thanks!!